# How can I bypass 429 Too Many Request error on c#?

Tags: c#, http, search

So, I am trying to make a plagiarism checker with `c#` and `google` and after a few debugs, my code does not work anymore. I tried to see the exception and saw that it is a `429 Too Many Requests error`. What I want to do is either bypass this error with something (as I can still access google from the same pc) or get a time that I can try again. How can I do that?

Code for searching:

```
private void SearchAndWrite(string text)
        {

            string txtKeyWords = text;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] ResultsBuffer = new byte[8192];
            string SearchResults = "http://google.com/search?q=" + txtKeyWords.Trim();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SearchResults);
            //request.Headers["X-My-Custom-Header"] = "'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5)\\AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari / 537.36'";

            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                count = resStream.Read(ResultsBuffer, 0, ResultsBuffer.Length);
                string tempString = null;
                do
                {
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResultsBuffer, 0, count);
                        sb.Append(tempString);
                    }
                }

                while (count > 0);
                string sbb = sb.ToString();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
                html.LoadHtml(sbb);
                HtmlNode doc = html.DocumentNode;
                foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    //HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                    string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                    if (!hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("GOOGLE") && hrefValue.ToString().Contains("/url?q=") && hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("HTTP://"))
                    {
                        int index = hrefValue.IndexOf("&");
                        if (index > 0)
                        {
                            hrefValue = hrefValue.Substring(0, index);
                            listBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue.Replace("/url?q=", ""));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "An error has occurred!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            

            

            
        }
```

Comment: Try adding [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't see all the code , and can't see any recursing I assume you are making multiple calls to SearchAndWrite , you probably need to rate limit your queries.

Try putting a 5 or 10 second wait in between each request, if the problem goes away then you need to find a way to not hammer google with queries.

Consider using a queue, and worker loop.

Comment: I will try it, thanks! But I have a question, when will this error disappear? Because now, I can't debug my code because of this error. I mean, is there a way for the app to tell the user that "Wait X seconds before trying again" ?

Comment: user a timer to enable and disable the button ?? I assume there is a button

Comment: What is the exact time to try again then?

Comment: Because this error occurred 5 hours ago and I am still unable to get it working.

Comment: so you have probably had your IP blocked by cloudflare or some other 'protection' layer infront of googles servers. Try using a VPN.